# Should I reveal details of a job offer to another company?

Tags: job-offer, hiring-process, negotiation

I am in the process of interviewing for a job with two companies. Company A knows I am also interviewing with Company B. Company B has already made me an offer and company A is asking me about the details of the offer.

I do not feel comfortable about revealing such details. Should I keep it to myself?

Comment: It's these kind of people that make we want to say something rude like, "If you were any good at your job, you would know what they offered me."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They're asking for details so they can weigh their offer against the competing one. As far as I can tell, revealing the terms of the other offer will lead to one of two outcomes:

1. You are dropped from consideration
2. You are made a slightly better offer

You may be dropped from consideration if they realize they cannot offer you as much as company B. If, on the other had, what they were preparing to offer is close to what B is offering, then they can match that.

The third option, not revealing anything at all, yields this:

3. You will continue the process without undue influence from B

You may be dropped from consideration 'naturally', or be made an offer much lower or higher than B's. Personally, this is the one I'd go with, and I'll explain why.

There is no reason to let one company influence the other. This can only work to your detriment, by excluding the possibility of a higher offer from A. I would reply with a variation of the following:

> I'm afraid the offer details are confidential and I must treat them as such. Rest assured, should an offer be extended from you, it will be treated with the same confidentiality.

If they insist you give them a figure, it'll be the same as negotiating your salary from the beginning, only now you're negotiating B's offer instead of your current salary. Naturally, you don't want them to know any details, as this can work to your detriment. So, stick to your guns.

By the way, take a moment to read [Kalzumeus' guide to salary negotiation](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2012/01/23/salary-negotiation/), if you haven't already. I cannot recommend it highly enough.

Comment: @Nat - I agree with rath, but they could be asking about your private conversation with the other company to determine if you are trustworthy, and use that to drop you from consideration. Otherwise that would mean you'd simply take their offer back to the other place and repeat the process. Don't be nickel and dimed, they're simply going to make a significantly higher offer or not; they ought to have not been so close if they were serious. If they're tight wad during the interview it won't be better after you're hired; getting necessary supplies, and raises or bonuses. Drop them for asking.